# new Imageick() dont run

Tags: php, imagemagick

i have installed imagemagick, php5-imagick on my ubuntu 12.04 Server.
Now if i want to use

```
$image = new Image()
```

there stoped!

```
            echo "1";
            $img1 = new Imagick();
            $img1 -> readImage("/the/absolut/path/to/image.png");
            echo "1,3";
            // Upload image
            $img2 = new Imagick("dl/$md5");
            echo "2";

            $img1->compositeImage( $img2, imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0 );
            echo "3";

            echo $img1;
```

but it gives only "1" out. Why? What is wrong?

Comment: Google `Enable error reporting + PHP`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info under **What should I do before asking a question?**

Comment: if i use "identify" on shell. he ask: convert: improper image header `sn_logo.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3242. BUT WHY?

Comment: the same error by the way on enabled error reporting